# Single test fails in PhantomJS but works in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: ember.js, phantomjs, ember-cli, acceptance-testing, testem

I have a single acceptance test in Ember.js 1.10, Ember CLI 0.1.12 which fails on PhantomJS but runs fine in both Chrome and Firefox. I've tried to debug this for 2 days but I'm running out of ideas. Name of the test is **user can view logged-only pages when he is logged**. Basically when you are not logged and you try to access `classic` route, for example `/about` you are redirected to `start.login` in `beforeModel` hook of classic route:

```
beforeModel: ->
  if not @controllerFor('application').get 'logged'
    @transitionTo 'start.login'
```

When you are on `start.login` and you will give correct name and username, `logIn` action in `StartLoginController` will be called:

```
logIn: ->
  if not @get('logged')
    @get('controllers.application').send 'logIn', @get('username'), @get('password'), @get('rememberMe')
```

Which calls following action in `ApplicationController`:

```
  actions:
    logIn: (username, password, remember) ->
      if not @get 'logged'
        $.ajax
          url: @get('apiURL') + '/auth/login'
          type: 'POST'
          data:
            name: username
            password: password
            remember: remember
          xhrFields:
            withCredentials: true #ensure CORS
        .then (response) =>
          if response.success

            expires = if remember then new Date(response.cookieExpiration) else null

            $.cookie 'auth_user_id', response.user.id,
              expires: expires
              path: '/'

            $.cookie 'auth_expiration', response.cookieExpiration,
              expires: expires
              path: '/'

            @setProperties
              logged: true
              'controllers.auth.userId': response.user.id

            @transitionToRoute 'classic.index'
        , =>
          @send 'openModal', 'modal/wrong-credentials'

      false
```

And this works fine even in PhantomJS. Other tests pass. Actions are called correctly, properties are set correctly, cookies are set correctly. Even `beforeModel` hook correctly calls(or not) `transitionTo` method. I've thought that issue with PhantomJS is with some async order of calling things but I've tried wrapping code in `Ember.run` and `andThen` in many places. No luck at all.

`testem.json`:

```
{
  "framework": "qunit",
  "test_page": "tests/index.html?hidepassed",
  "launch_in_ci": [
    "PhantomJS"
  ],
  "launch_in_dev": [
    "PhantomJS",
    "Chrome",
    "Firefox"
  ]
}
```

Acceptance test `login-test.coffee`(failing test is the last one):

```
`import Ember from 'ember'`
`import startApp from '../helpers/start-app'`

application = null

run = Ember.run

login = ->
  visit '/'

  fillIn '[placeholder=Login]', 'test'
  fillIn '[placeholder=Hasło]', 'test'

  click '.button-login'

clearCookies = ->
  cookies = $.cookie()

  for cookie of cookies
    $.removeCookie cookie,
      path: '/'

  cookies = document.cookie.split ';'
  for i in [0...cookies.length] by 1
    equals = cookies[i].indexOf '='
    name = if equals > -1 then cookies[i].substr(0, equals) else cookies[i]
    document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"

module 'Acceptance: Login',
  setup: ->
    application = startApp()

    clearCookies()

    time = new Date()

    $.mockjaxSettings.logging = false

    $.mockjax
      type: 'POST'
      url: 'api/v1/auth/login'
      dataType: 'json'
      responseText:
        success: true
        user:
          id: 1
        cookieExpiration: time.setDate time.getDate() + 14

    $.mockjax
      type: 'GET'
      url: '/api/v1/users/1'
      dataType: 'json'
      responseText:
        user:
          id: 1

    $.mockjax
      type: 'GET'
      url: '/api/v1/statuses' # ?limitOld=10&friends=true&comments[limit]=5
      data:
        comments:
          limit: 5
        friends: true
        limitOld: 10
      responseText:
        statuses: {}

    $.mockjax
      type: 'GET'
      url: '/api/v1/getRandomQuote'

    $.mockjax
      type: 'GET'
      url: '/api/v1/statuses/?friends=true&count=true'
      responseText:
        count: 0

    $.mockjax
      type: 'GET'
      url: '/api/v1/meals'

    $.mockjax
      type: 'GET'
      url: '/api/v1/notifications'

    $.mockjax
      type: 'GET'
      url: '/api/v1/notifications'
      data:
        read: false
      responseText: {}

    return

  teardown: ->
    $.mockjax.clear()

    clearCookies()

    run application, 'destroy'

test 'user lands on default page when he is not logged', ->
  expect 1

  visit '/'

  andThen ->
    equal currentPath(), 'start.login'

test 'login page is displayed when you are trying to access logged-only page', ->
  expect 1

  visit '/kitchen'

  andThen ->
    equal currentPath(), 'start.login'

test 'user can login', ->
  expect 2

  appController = application.__container__.lookup 'controller:application'

  equal appController.get('logged'), false, 'user is not logged before login'

  login()

  andThen ->
    ok appController.get 'logged', 'user is logged when response is success'

test 'user can view logged-only pages when he is logged', ->
  expect 2
  console.log '-- LOGGED-ONLY TEST START --'

  visit '/about'

  andThen ->
    equal currentPath(), 'start.login'

  login()

  visit '/about'

  andThen ->
    equal currentPath(), 'classic.about'
```

And finally output from tests:

```
TEST'EM 'SCRIPTS!                                                          
Open the URL below in a browser to connect.                                
http://localhost:7357/                                                     
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓                                                            
 PhantomJS 1.9┃  Firefox 37.0                                              
  198/199 ✘   ┃  199/199 ✔                                                 
              ┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
Acceptance: Login: user can view logged-only pages when he is logged
    ✘ failed
         expected classic.about
         actual start.login

-- LOGGED-ONLY TEST START --
```

*I don't think `classic.about` is source of error, because replacing it with other child routes of `classic` resource result in same PhantomJS failing test.*

Okay so it seems that problem lies in model for `ClassicRoute`(commenting that makes test pass):

```
  model: ->
    new Promise (resolve, reject) =>
      @store.find 'user', @controllerFor('auth').get('userId')
        .then (user) =>
          @controllerFor('auth').set 'user', user
          resolve
            profile: user.get 'profile'
```

Comment: Upgrading PhantomJS to version 2.x may work for you.

Comment: Last npm version seems to be packaged with PhantomJS 1.9.8. Seems like PhantomJS 2.0 will never be released on Linux because they have got some problems with preparing binaries and I have to wait for 2.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've split logic in two hooks instead of one and it works now:

```
  beforeModel: ->
    if not @controllerFor('application').get 'logged'
      @transitionTo 'start.login'
    else
      @store
      .find 'user', @controllerFor('auth').get('userId')
      .then (user) =>
        @controllerFor('auth').set 'user', user
        @set 'profileId', user.get('profile.id')    

  model: ->
    @store.find 'profile', @get('profileId')
```

Comment: hmm that's bizarre, i seen a lot of bizarre stuff so far testing also, can't you just return from the model hook instead of manually wrapping it in a promise as that will wait till the promise finishes for you

Comment: I have to return model as object with profile property - which is resolved from `store.find` so I have like 2 promises here.